# VBA Copy+Paste Code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a subset of a macro I'm writing that needs a bit of modification & help from all you geniuses.

Sheet "Regions!A6:R6 contain formulas pulling data out of a table. I want "Regions!A6:R6 copied as values, then pasted in "Temp!A1""

Would you be able to help modify this code to accomplish this end goal?

```
Sub Testing()

' Gets Number of Row in Regions Sheet
Sheets("Regions").Activate
LR1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


'Creates a New Worksheet and copy's the data from regions, interst the copied data into the
'New Temp Sheet and then removes the duplicates to create your list of unique items to filter on

'Creating the New WorkSheet
Sheets.Add.Name = "Temp"

'Copy the data
Sheets("Regions").Activate
Range("A6:R" & LR1).Select
Selection.Copy

'Paste the data into Temp Sheet
Sheets("Temp").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: You got two (almost identical, but one is clearly the best) solutions. BTW if you want to stick to your code you have to change `ActiveSheet.Paste` to `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. But all that _activation_ and _selection_ of yours is the most inefficient and unreliable way of doing things!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a genius, but I'm someone who always tries to apply good coding practices. First thing I'd get rid of those `Select` and `Activate` stuff, simplifying the code, and then I assign `Value` instead of using copy/paste, which will get you rid of the formulas and copy values only.

```
Sub Testing()
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Temp"
    With Sheets("Regions").Range("A6:R" & Sheets("Regions").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        Sheets("Temp").Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).value = .value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @user3598756, yeah, only difference is that yours is copying only column "A". seems to me that OP want to copy columns A to R.

Comment: ., it's not that it _seems_ , it _is_ like that! I'll edit my answer

Comment: @user3598756 oh please dont! :P

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
Sub Testing()
    'Creating the New WorkSheet
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Temp"

    'Copy the data
    With Sheets("Regions")
        With .Range("R6", .cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            Sheets("Temp").Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```